# indexNew.html:140 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null at HTMLImageElement.onclick (indexNew.html:140)

Tags: javascript, html

I have tried my code in w3school, in the try section, and it worked fine. Then I add it to my own web site and it does not work.

I have to tell you that I got all the ideas from here - my solution is the one proposed in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/838878/replace-image-with-a-video-embeded) .

The error message in the console is as stated above: indexNew.html:140 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null
    at HTMLImageElement.onclick (indexNew.html:140)

My code is this:

```
                        <div id="videocontainer1">
                        <img src="images/youtube-labour_of_love.jpg" alt="Labour of love Dance" onclick="document.getElementById('videocontainer1').innerHTML = embedCode1;" height="500" width="600" />
                    </div>
```

and, following another questions's solution, I have inserted the script just before the  tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var embedCode1 = '<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/Mn-9mPzo-E0?rel=0" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>'
```

As I said, this code runns fine when I try it on w3school.... and please be very literal with me, I am not a programmer, I just maintain that one web site, built on a template....

Thank you very much for any help you can provide.

The code from W3school is this:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>**************</p>
<div id="videocontainer">
    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/248797/pexels-photo-248797.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940" onclick="document.getElementById('videocontainer').innerHTML = embedCode;" height="500" width="600" />
</div>
<p>**************</p>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var embedCode = '<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/Mn-9mPzo-E0?rel=0" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>'
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You named it `videocontainer1`. You have `videocontainer` in your `code`.

Comment: Thank you, I have corrected this, now they are both called videocontainer1. It is unfortunately still not working

Comment: You want the `<script>` before the `#videocontainer1`.

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately this also did not rectify the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Doing a function from the 'onClick' event works. Try this.

```js
function showVideo() {
  document.getElementById('videocontainer').innerHTML = '<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/Mn-9mPzo-E0?rel=0" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
}
```

```html
<div id="videocontainer">
    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/248797/pexels-photo-248797.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940" onclick="showVideo()" height="500" width="600" />
</div>
```

Comment: .. .erm, as I said, you've got to be very lteral with me.... How do I pass an argument? Is it showVideo(var)   ? Because I have two different videos I need to embed on this page...

Comment: Blak Dave, thank you very much, I got it to work, rather unelegantly, but that does not matter for me :-) So thank you very much!

Comment: You can pass the container id (that you want to use for the video embed) into the `showVideo` function.. e.g. `onClick="showVideo('videoContainer')"` then from the function, `function showVideo(id) { document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = 'embed code goes here'; }`

Comment: @VicGeb Since my answer works for you, can you upvote it or something?

Comment: I did, but it said that it will keep a record of my vote but since I have less than 15 myself does not show... Sorry!