# Open a new page when a video is played

Tags: video

I need to open a new page when a video embeded from Youtube is played clicking on a image.  Best option could be load a image where the video should be and on click replace the image with the video start playing. For this last one I have checked several posts (see below). How could I play the video in a new page?

Thanks in advance

[replace image with a video embeded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/838878/replace-image-with-a-video-embeded)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the target attribute of the a element to _blank to open it in a new tab or window.

Example:

```
        <a href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/zX54DIpacNE" target=_blank>
    <img src="url/of/the.img">
</a>
```

Although IMHO it's better to just link to the youtube page of the video instead of embedding it since you are opening it in a new tab already

Comment: Thanks, but could I put this code but using the <iframe> tag? I had troubles with this tag.

Comment: try this <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e4Qqm2s3g84">
  <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>

</body>
</html>

Comment: But I suppose if I use <iframe> the code line should be the following?
<iframe src="youtube.com/watch?v=e4Qqm2s3g84" target=_blank> <img src="url/of/the.img"> </iframe>

Comment: The img is goint to be hidden by the frame